# gnuplot: how to use a*(10^b) format on axis

Tags: axis, scale, gnuplot

I am using really big numbers (milions) on my x-axis, so when I use

```
set format x %6.0f
```

I got big numbers like 25000000. That is quite nice, but takes much space, so there are only few labels and reader losts information.

When I exclude setting format, I get something like 2e+07, what is quite unfriendly and unusual to reader according to my opinion.

I would like format like 25*(10^6), so the number would be first and then multiplied by 10^n, or something very similiar to that. I think that would be the best solution, if the x-axis is long about 30000000 points or even more.

However, reading manuals, e.g. "How do I change the format of the numbers ?" from [http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/tics-e.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20100829220255/http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/tics-e.html) did not help me much.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

All format specifiers that gnuplot has to offer can be found [here](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-18600043.21.2).

If you don't like the 2e+07 format you could try setting the format with

```
set format x "%.0s*10^{%T}"
```

which gives you a format like 15*10^6.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! You brought me to idea of %.0s MB, what looks really pretty! ;-) Thats exactly what I needed.

Comment: Note that this will use _engineering_ notation instead of scientific. This means that instead of e.g. 2×10⁷ you'll get 20×10⁶. For scientific notation see the [answer by sri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45481272/673852).

Comment: Not working for me in gnuplot 5.4 patchlevel 1. Resulting x ticks are like `15*10^{113*10^{832`.

Answer (score 8):

Also one can use the following to obtain scientific notation with cross symbol: 2x10^6

> set format x "%2.0t{/Symbol \264}10^{%L}"

Comment: On my gnuplot 5.0 compiled on Linux I get normal cross symbol even with literal "×" character.

Comment: On 5.4 patchlevel 1, this gives me a complaint `Format character mismatch: %L is only valid with %l` when I actually try to plot. And the actual result doesn't seem right. It's giving x axis ticks like `1{/Symb 8{/Sym 6{/Symb 5{/Sym`.